# Windows server has trouble connecting to file shares

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, server-message-block, networking, shares

Server is running Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, Rest are Server 2008 R2 Standard
I think its an issue with the credentials that it's using?

This is a backup server that connects to the admin shares of the other servers and backs them up.  It has connectivity issues, it can connect to some machines but not others.  But this issue is unique to this server.

I can ping the others servers, and if I run the troubleshooter then it says "File and Printer sharing is enabled but the server is not responding to requests"

Attempts to connect to these servers from other machines are always successful.

Any ideas?

EDIT:SOMETIMES if I use the FQDN then it will connect successfully.

Comment: so if you do a \\r2standardserver\ipc$ from the enterprise server does it fail always or is it sporadic? Also do a "dir \\r2standardserver\ipc$"  at the command prompt you may see a more discriptive error message.

Comment: If it were an authentication problem (invalid credentials) then it would never connect. If it sometimes connects using the FQDN then it sounds like a name resolution problem to me. I would verify name resolution on this server and your network.

Comment: It'd definitely not name resolution, DNS is functioning perfectly, and both hostname and FQDN resolve to the correct IP (ARP also resolves to the correct MAC)

Comment: @tonyroth
I can't access shares at all, if i just do "\\server" It will hangup the same way it would if you put a non-existent machine there.  The only difference being that the troubleshooter will recognize there is a system on the other side. Trying to access the share through the command line gives the error "The network path was not found/" Same if you use the FQDN.

Windows Network Diagnostics returns "file and print sharing resource([servername] is online but isn't responding to connection attempts."

Comment: so if you do a \\ipadress\sharename does it work everytime?

Comment: It does not, All connections (names) are hit or miss but most of them don't work more often than not.

Comment: I am also wondering why this was downvoted?  On another note, I'm still having the issue.

I also tried creating a new admin user and tried from that login, same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think I've really found the problem, but I enabled the second NIC on the machine and now its working fine so I don't know what was causing the problem unfortunately but it is functioning now.  Presumably something wrong with the other NIC, but everything else was working fine, including connections to some other servers.